# Makefile for a project

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++

I have a Makefile for a project using regex. Thus I need to use g++-4.9 and c++11.

```
BIN   = bin
OBJ   = src/main.o src/time2.o  src/except.o src/except2.o src/struct.o src/index.o
FLAGS = -lncurses
CC    = g++-4.9  -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb

all: compile

run: compile
    ./$(BIN)

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN) $(OBJ)

compile: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(FLAGS)
```

but when I try to make compile:

> ```
> g++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp In file included from
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/regex:35:0,
>              from src/time2.h:16,
>              from src/main.cpp:3: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
> file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
> standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
> with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.  #error This
> file requires compiler and library support for the \   ^ In file
> included from src/main.cpp:5:0: src/struct.h:99:18: error: ‘regex’ has
> not been declared   bool isnamegood(regex x,const string& name);
>                                     ^
> ```

so I don't understand what is wrong, may you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `compile` target already depends on the object files! But they aren't build yet, so make tries to find a rule to build them. Because you have not defined a custom rule, it uses the [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Compiling C++ programs n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or
>   n.C with a recipe of the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’. We
>   encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of
>   ‘.C’.

This rule will of course not use the flags you set in `CC`. This explains why the `gcc` command line printed by `make` does not match your `CC`. You can test this by running make with `--no-builtin-rules`, as this should disable all the implicit rules.

A good idea in such cases is to run make with `-d` or `--debug`, I think this should display rule evaluations.

Comment: Side note, you should always use --no-builtin-rules IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `c` macros, use the `c++` macros

```
CXX= g++-4.9
CXXFLAGS=  -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb
```

Then the default rules should pick them up and you need to type less in your makefile.

Also see the [complete list of variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) (macros) used by Make